# Execute native T-SQL with Spring

Tags: sql-server, spring, t-sql

I have a SQL statement that works correctly for MS-SQL (SQL Azure):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @UserId INT
SET @UserId = 1
select @UserId as some_value
COMMIT
```

(My actual SQL is more complicated, this is just an example).

How can I execute this native T-SQL code from Spring? Or more specifically, how can I get Spring to send this T-SQL to the DB engine for execution?

I tried using the jdbcTemplate.executeForObject but it does not seem to support this SQL. The exception is UncategorizedSQLException.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction handling with spring can, and should, be performed declaratively using annotations on your [service layer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Just use vanilla jdbc for [creating sprocs etc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#creating_javadb_sql_jdbc) or running a normal prepared statement/query and set [con.setAutoCommit(false);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

Comment: Because of a variety of issues on our side, using Spring annotations would require us to write a custom JPA Isolation level. I am exploring options to avoid this. We can express a solution cleanly in T-SQL but do not know how to get it executed in Spring.

Comment: why involve spring at all, just do a jdbc prepared statement then

Comment: I am attempting to use Spring because that is what our backend is written in. I just can't use the transaction annotations for this because the isolation level we need is not supported by JPA, which forces us to write our own isolation level.